# Open new window without focus on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have such situation. I try to open a window with `window.open` function new window was opened in a front of main window, how can i open it in background of main window, without focus on new. Is it possible to do such thing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you seek is called a ["pop-under" window](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/popunder.shtml)

- Open a new window using [`let handle = window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)
- Lose focus of the new window by using [`handle.blur()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/blur)
- The return focus to your existing window using [`window.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus)

Example:

```
var handle = window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/');
handle.blur();
window.focus();
```

However, it's not a guarantee as user browser settings may override this behavior, especially pop-up blockers.

Comment: Does not work with Chrome v108.

Answer (score -4):

No you cant open window behind the main window. if you are using `window.open()` then it will be top of the main window. that's how the pop up windows works.
alternatively you can do this

```
Window.open(); 
yourMainWindow.focus();
```

Comment: Ok, maybe there are some other ways to open new window in background, without `window.open()` function

Comment: @AntonSementsov What are the other ways to do the same through js.

Answer (score -17):

Try using the Following

```
window.open("http://localhost/123", '_blank');
```

Comment: it "work"s, it just doesn't do what was requested.