# How to open a url in new window without losing the focus of current window

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to open a url in new window without losing the focus of current window .
I want to open a new url for every 20 secs of time.
I used the following code in a page where the function is called after some time period but not working

```
var win=window.open(url,'_blank');
     window.focus();
```

Comment: See this: **[Open new window without focus on it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133605/open-new-window-without-focus-on-it)**

Comment: Give me the link of your website to add it to my blocked list

Comment: i think this [link](http://www.infimum.dk/HTML/JSwindows.html) may be help full for you

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522565/how-to-stay-on-current-window-when-the-link-opens-in-new-tab

Comment: why blocked list?? @HamZa ... anyways i used the focus and blur but not works for me

Comment: @SekharSeerapu I think you didn't get me. I'm already annoyed when I get a simple alert, let alone some random new windows **every** 20 secs. Are you insane ?

Comment: @HamZa hahahah...funny, it's my client dream.i have to fulfill his requirement.

Comment: @SekharSeerapu Well atleast tell him that it's annoying and that it will chase most of *his* clients away.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you... but it is not recommended to open new popups every 20 second since this will be the worst user experience ever

1. create a new popup window using window.open()
2. blur newly created window using window.blur()
3. focus your main window using window.focus()