# jQuery simulate ctrl + click when opening new tab on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, onclick

I have written the following code in jQuery:

```
  $(document).on("click", "#datatable-responsive tbody tr td button.btn", function () {
     window.open('somelinkhere', '_blank');
  });
```

So the problem here is when I do it like this , and it works flawlessly, the new tab that is opened gets the focus, and I don't want that to happen. Instead I would like to simulate these two keystrokes:  ctrl + left mouse click

so that my main windows stays in focus and new tab gets opened...

How could I do this in jQuery?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133605/open-new-window-without-focus-on-it

Comment: @Tokiin just read a few replies there, how would I reflect this to my case?

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#datatable-responsive tbody tr td button.btn").click(function() {
    var thisWind = window.location;
    window.location = ('http://www.google.lt');
    window.open(thisWind, '_blank');
 });    
})
```

Pretty simple - first window location changed to the popup url and then the primary window reopened.

Comment: Looks good working ... but it leds 2 page loads .... doesn't it ?? there might b some other way :(

Comment: @Rush.2707 Yes, there are two loads, but here we need a work around and only this came into my head..

Answer (score 0):

You could create an anchor element and trigger a `ctrl + click` on that element:

```
$("<a/>", {href: "https://www.google.com/"}).get(0)
    .dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {ctrlKey: true}));
```