# New window without focus

Tags: javascript, window, internet-explorer-11

I know this question has been "answered" multiple times, but nothing works in my case. I have tried with focus(),blur(). ect...I am using IE 11. Anyone have any idea? I want to open a new window, but keep focus on the original window....

```
 btn.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {


                        var url = "https://XXXX/XXXXX/XXXXXX/";

                        var newWin = window.open(url, "_blank");
                         window.focus();

                        ev.stopPropagation();
                    }, true);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open new window without focus on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133605/open-new-window-without-focus-on-it)

Comment: ^ Just to add to that, the top answer does have a disclaimer that _your mileage may vary_, depending on how the user's browser handles this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer example below may work for you.

Code in parent page.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function openPopUP() {
  window.open('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\95.html','NewWin',
            'toolbar=no,status=no,width=350,height=135')
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Original Page:<br>
<a href="javascript:openPopUP();">Click to open popup</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Code in child page.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function abc()
{
window.parent.opener.focus(); 
}


</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="abc()">
child page
</body>
</html>
```